# Write console.log() to the command line in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After I run `grunt serve` to have my AngularJS app running locally... I can't figure out how to have things write to the terminal window besides other Grunt tasks.

[image: pic of my terminal window]

Specifically, I would like to have the ability to write out things using `console.log()` to my terminal window -- in addition of course to seeing them in the browser's javascript console.

Is that possible & how would I do that?

Comment: you can use http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log instead

Comment: I saw that, very cool. I will look into it more and see if I can figure out how to use Grunt log for that purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily unless you run your javascript in a headless browser like [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or execute it in [node](https://nodejs.org/en/).

`console.log()` displays in the consoles of browsers like chrome or firefox because they "execute" your code. Grunt is just building out your javascript files.. not executing them

Answer (score 1):

Your command line is representative of your server - you would need to be running `console.log()` in your server side code (or whatever is language appropriate for your backend).

Answer (score 1):

This might be blindingly obvious to others, but for a beginner at Angular, when I was calling console.log() I was expecting to see output in my node.js server window, but in fact the output is shown in the web console.

For Firefox:  hamburger menu, Web developer, web console (or Ctrl-Shift-K)

For Chrome: hamburger menu, More tools, Developer tools, and select Console tab in pane on the right.